# How to fix 'If statement' always going for 'else'

Tags: autohotkey

I have a very simple 'IfEqual' statement, that always goes to 'else'

I tried it with the 'If' statement, like 'If %GuiText1%=Var1' and 'If (GuiText1 = Var1)', but got the same result

```
Gui, Add, Button, x25 y8 cBlue vSA , Var1
Gui, Add, Button, x20 y8 cRed vSD , Var2
GuiControl, Hide, SD
Gui,Show

{
ControlGetText, GuiText1,, new.ahk    //to get the button-text from the window
msgbox, %GuiText1%    //to check if its the right variable
IfEqual, %GuiText1%, Var1
        {
        msgbox, 1
        }
    else
        {
        msgbox, 2
        }
}
```

It always goes straigth to 'else'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names in an [expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) are not enclosed in percent signs.

```
IfEqual, GuiText1, Var1
```

[IfEqual](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfEqual.htm) is deprecated and not recommended for use in new scripts.
Use the [If Statement](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#if-statement) instead:

```
If GuiText1 = Var1   ; traditional mode
```

or, even better

```
If (GuiText1 = "Var1")   ; expressional mode
```